# Draw an ASCIIrisk

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

There are an abundance of questions involving drawing shapes using asterisks - so I thought, with so many asterisks out there, we should draw one, using the ASCII table.

### Challenge

Your task is to write a program or function which takes no input, and outputs this exact text:

```
          !
         "#
         $%
         &'
         ()
         *+
         ,-
         ./
         01
23456789:;<=>?@ABCDEF
GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[
        \]^_
       `a  bc
      de    fg
     hi      jk
    lm        no
   pq          rs
  tu            vw
 xy              z{
|}                ~
```

For reference, [this site](http://www.ascii-code.com/) lists the complete ASCII table.

## Rules

- The output should be the exact text, as shown above. Leading/trailing whitespace is allowed.
- Standard golfing loopholes apply - no reading this ASCIIrisk from the internet, etc.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution (in bytes) wins.

Comment: I want to try this challenge... but it sounds kinda _risky_.

Please excuse my terrible humor.

Comment: Stack Overflow has a NoBadJokes policy so I'm going to have to ignore that comment. Sorry but it policy

Comment: Okay. Sorry for violating the policy. Thank you for ignoring my comment by replying to it.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Don't judge a challenge by its cover. Now you've missed a really good challenge just because of your prejudice.

Comment: @2x-1 I can't tell if you're being ironic.

Comment: Someone has to make a script replacing asterisks with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>40</s> <s>38</s> <s>37</s> <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
žQ2ô376S3*£`2ôvyN·ð×ýð«}rsJ2äsr)˜.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ATIAzf//xb5RMsO0Mzc2UzMqwqNgMsO0dnlOwrfDsMOXw73DsMKrfXJzSjLDpHNyKcucLmP//w)

**Explanation**

```
žQ                                   # push the printable ascii chars
  2ô                                 # split into pairs
    376S                             # split the number 376 into a list of digits
        3*                           # multiply each by 3 to get [9,21,18]
          £                          # divide the pairs of ascii chars into 
                                     # pieces of these sizes
           `                         # flatten list to stack
            2ô                       # split the "legs" of the asterisk into pairs of pairs
              v                      # loop over the pairs of pairs
               yN·ð×ý                # join the pairs by index*2 spaces
                     ð«              # append a space
                       }             # end loop
                        rs           # move the middle section to top of stack
                          J2ä        # convert to a string split into 2 pieces
                             sr      # rearrange the stack in the correct order
                               )˜    # wrap in a flattened list
                                 .c  # pad each element with spaces on either side
```

Comment: `žQ2ôÐ9£s30£R21£RøsrR18£R2ôvyN·ð×ý})˜.C»`, I got 39, but I think you can shave some off with ZIP.

Comment: @carusocomputing: I don't think zip is very useful here since we want the characters to remain sequential. Splitting everything in pairs at the start was a good idea though. It feels wasteful using so many **r** and **s** but I don't see a way around it.

Comment: [**31 bytes**](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP8wNWFiMWX//8W@UcSGMsO0Mzc2UzMqwqNgMsO0zrVOwrfDsMOXw719xaBKMsOkKcOAy5wuY///): `Ć` added after `žQ` so the `ð«` can be removed; `vy` to `ε`; `rs` to `Š`; `sr` removed and `À` added after the `)`.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 110 bytes

```python
s='%c';print(('\n'.join(['%10c%c']*9+[s*21]*2+[' '*(8-i)+s*2+'  '*i+s*2for i in range(9)]))%(*range(32,128),))
```

Generates the template

```python
         xx
         xx
         xx
         xx
         xx
         xx
         xx
         xx
         xx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxx
       xx  xx
      xx    xx
     xx      xx
    xx        xx
   xx          xx
  xx            xx
 xx              xx
xx                xx
```

with `%c` for `x`, then uses string interpolation on `range(32,128)` to insert the ASCII values into the pattern.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#JYlLDoIwEECvMptmPkVD6wZiPEntwhAw42IwhfuXEnbvU7cXugmf/6K2E@Hb8P5b1SihC/3UVpbRp01iyBJ9QkCh4absW/IITfXEZS2goAblY9@ZRs7MjuSyR@xCHLhjrvUA)

Python 2 is one byte longer, with longer tuple unpacking but shorter `print`.

```python
s='%c';print('\n'.join(['%10c%c']*9+[s*21]*2+[' '*(8-i)+s*2+'  '*i+s*2for i in range(9)]))%tuple(range(32,128))
```

Comment: It deserves a Eiffel Tower similarity award!

Answer (score 11):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>54</s>, 50 bytes

```
¬ ~9ñ9É 11|á
ñ2ñ20lá
ñ$18é 9ñ^y|Ehé
Pf xxywk$hP>ñd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@39ojUKd5eGNloc7FQwNaw4v5Dq80QiIDHLATBVDi8MrFYDycZU1rhmHV3IFpClUVFSWZ6tkBNgd3pjy/z8A)

Unlike usual, this program does not contain any unprintable characters.

Explanation:

```
¬ ~                     " Insert the entire printable ASCII range
   9ñ           ñ       " 9 times:
     9É                 "   Insert 9 spaces at the beginning of this line
        11|             "   Move to the 11'th column on this line
           á<CR>        "   And append a newline after the 11'th column
```

Now the buffer looks like this:

```
          !
         "#
         $%
         &'
         ()
         *+
         ,-
         ./
         01
23456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Now we build up the middle:

```
2ñ        ñ             " Two times:
  20l                   "   Move 20 characters to the right (because 'l' == 'right', duh)
     á<CR>              "   Append a newline
```

Here's where it gets a little weird.

```
$                       " Move to the end of this line 
 18é                    " Insert 18 spaces before the last character
     9ñ                 " Repeat the following 9 times:
       ^                "   Move to the first non-whitespace character
        y|              "   Yank all the whitespace before the current character. 
                        "   We'll call this the "Leading whitespace register"
          E             "   Move to the end of the current WORD (up to before a space)
           h            "   Move back one character
            é<CR>       "   And insert a newline before the current character
P                       "   Paste the leading whitespace for indentation
 f                      "   Move forward to a space
   xx                   "   Delete two characters
                        "   (Note how we are inbetween the two bottom branches right now)
     yw                 "   Yank everything upto the next branch (all spaces)
                        "   We'll paste this on the line up so that we can yank it again later
                        "   To keep track of how far apart the branches are
       k$               "   Move up a line and to the end of that line
         hP             "   Move back a character and paste the whitespace we yanked
           >            "   Indent this line by one space
            ñ           "   End the loop
```

Here's an important note. The `>` command is actually an *operator*, which means it doesn't do anything without an argument, the text to operate on. For example,

```
>_      "Indent the current line
>>      "Indent the current line
>j      "Indent the current and next line
>G      "Indent every line
```

But since this command is in a loop, we can save a character by not giving an operator. At the end of a loop, if any operator is pending it will fill in `_` (the current line) as an argument implicitly.

Now I'll admit this loop is a little weird, and it can be hard to keep track of what all text should look like at any given moment. So you can use [this simpler program](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@39ojUKd5eGNloc7FQwNaw4v5Dq80QiIDHLATBVDi8MrFQ43HN4YV1njmnF4JVdAmkJFRWV5tkpGgN3////NAA) to see what it will look like after **N** loops.

If you set it to 9, you can see that we have a little bit of extra text to get rid of. (Just the current line).

So we delete the current line with `dd`. But wait! You know how I said that operators have to take an argument which is sometime implicitly filled in? Arguments are also implicitly filled at the end of the program. So rather than `dd` or `d_` (which are equivalent), we can simply to `d` and let V fill in the `_` for us.

Comment: Nice job abusing the implicit `ÿ` :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/index.html), 899 bytes

```
ill be honest with you
i expect a big solitude
i guess i had a guilt
my own idea being:i was real alone,i was a lonely human
also,i am still
o,i guess i was expecting a shift
i figured,surely i know i am tired of silence
now i dreamed for a shift
a magical desire cant come
i am barely a man,so i guess i see why a woman i see ignores myself
i know i am awful
o,a night of passion and a moment of love
i am truly the foolish person,every time i am saying i may recapture a love
o,i think i can,i think i can
i really do know i am unfit
o,i notice a lot,i think i know i am unfit
o,a novel,or perhaps poetry in code,i do enjoy the writing
and i shudder and i wonder in a moment
i was a weirdo,i was a freak,or like,i am creepy
o,i think i was a misfit
i know i am,really
o,i ought not concern myself
and sure,i am still some joyless man
i focused and i tried
a lasting solace and joy is nearby for me
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?ZVNbktwwCPz3KTiAT5DbMBa2yOjhEtI6Pv2msXc2s5UfVyGgaZq2pkQPoViLWKdDe6SzjklJ/uyydGJ66EZWk/YRBO/bEDNSihyQ3IamPuWT6lFIg6BctGy/lA42asKJOAF7vh@YPEgnxZG5TJysIsOZrGtKkwcvfC@/OQAPjRZ17Zi/6jaahNnwBZDSs9SDLpCuSFBdyTRJWWS6MwE0MhJrbd84TJk3XUAviKGNFi6dlpp9RUA9@EL3sjJbpX@8TISO6KmjIvn1olupTYzyaZLW6Z0VH@vw1ZiKbrE7v53NtBbi4hpmTC3Xe6ofX/N7Gxjfo4A1tLdIuzSrZZYPaUholhvd@HR9FERP6L3w3iHMJTSwXNAetTxRgA1/RpjkB8KcUN/4jrJqvzpL7brcWP2t9f9SrIZpaYbAoBl5N9qrdBDVAlGDnx8zpPyu91JHUz/r5AJAwDhCkEZ3dNTiATpf0kwv8xyiLdRvL62g//ShSZ9y@2hpIvv5Y@@7Nqs51zf28738VVuHXwb7gi2M08rrkE7JnfbmUvwMEB@bJDdEvnRc6zIMFrs36E0lwGKJ7TIv/h52HZF0AdSoCLfHeTkyy@fng8Nf)

Poetic is an esolang I made in 2018 for a class project. It's basically brainfuck with word-lengths instead of symbols.

This poem is...depressing.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) <s>170</s> <s>165</s> <s>155</s> 147 bytes

I've golfed this so much, I've forgotten how it works...

```py
i=b=0
for x in range(32,127):a=x%2<1;c=x>90;d=x<50;print(end=[' '*9*d,['\n'+' '*(8-i),'  '*~-i][b]][c]*a+chr(x)+'\n'*(x==70or d*x%2));b^=a;i+=b*c*a
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#FY1LDsIgFAD3noKNAR40oTWmVvq8CGLCp1U2aIgLVl4d291MMsm0hB7VYX0XUknKpLj8XNhpkP0w8qvDehzmXgest0npiHU@K/0pKX/ZkiMaSihMEKWh90zFbuzSJS4p2fDXJWu8tSZYcCK8Cqtc7CGwijiq7RlhG3Cu/QOdTgI9BHCt/QE)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>156</s> … <s>115</s> 114 bytes

Sadly, the infamous `String.fromCharCode()` costs 19 bytes.

```js
f=(x=y=k=1)=>k<96?String.fromCharCode(x-22?y/2^5&&(y>9?x-y+1>>1&&22-y-x>>1:x/2^5)?32:31+k++:(x=!++y,10))+f(x+1):''

console.log(f())
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
f = (                         // given:
  x =                         //   - x = current column
  y =                         //   - y = current row
  k = 1                       //   - k = current ASCII character code, minus 31
) =>                          //
  k < 96 ?                    // if we havent't reached character #127 (96 + 31):
    String.fromCharCode(      //   let's compute the next character
      x - 22 ?                //   if x is not equal to 22 (end of line):
        y / 2 ^ 5 && (        //     if y doesn't equal 10 or 11 (horizontal bar):
          y > 9 ?             //       and either y is greater than 9:
            x - y + 1 >> 1 && //         and we are not located on one of the
            22 - y - x >> 1   //         bottom diagonals
          :                   //       or y is less or equal to 9:
            x / 2 ^ 5         //         and x doesn't equal 10 or 11 (vertical bar)
        ) ?                   //     then:
          32                  //       append a space
        :                     //     else:
          31 + k++            //       append the next ASCII character
      :                       //   else:
        (x = !++y, 10)        //     increment y, reset x and append a LineFeed
    ) + f(x + 1)              //   do a recursive call with x + 1
  :                           // else:
    ''                        //   stop recursion
```

Comment: I think you can do `String.fromCharCode(...[...Array(n)].map(_=>k++))` to save 4 bytes.

Comment: @ETHproductions I like the idea of calling `String.fromCharCode()` on an array, but I went for another approach. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>153</s> 151 bytes

```
[32,49,2|?space$(9)+chr$(a)+chr$(a+1)][2|X=Y[a,a+20|X=X+chr$(c)]a=a+21?X][0,8|X=space$(8-d)[0,1|X=X+chr$(a+e)]X=X+space$(d*2)[2,3|X=X+chr$(a+f)]a=a+f?X
```

It's really just a series of FOR-loops and casting an int to a character (`chr$()`).

Sample output:

```
          !
         "#
         $%
         &'
         ()
         *+
         ,-
         ./
         01
23456789:;<=>?@ABCDEF
GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[
        \]^_
       `a  bc
      de    fg
     hi      jk
    lm        no
   pq          rs
  tu            vw
 xy              z{
|}                ~
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), 113 bytes

112 bytes of code + `-l` flag.

```perl
sub g{chr$c+++32}print$"x9,&g,&g for 0..8;print map&g,0..20for 0,1;print$"x-$_,&g,&g,$"x(16+2*$_),&g,&g for-8..0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#U1YsSC3KUdDN@V9cmqSQXp2cUaSSrK2tbWxUW1CUmVeiolRhqaOWDkQKaflFCgZ6ehbWYAmF3MQCoDhQwMgALKNjaA3ToasSD9GjA@RoGJppG2mpxGsijNG10NMz@P8fAA)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>110</s> <s>105</s> <s>103</s> <s>93</s> 91 bytes

```php
for(;$c<95;$y+=!$x%=21)echo"
"[$x],chr(31+($y%11<9&(max($y,10)-abs(9.5-$x++))%11<9?:++$c));
```

prints a leading newline. Run with `-nr` or [test it online](https://tio.run/nexus/php#HcmxDkAwEADQ3V@QI3c5xBFDteJDxEBDughhqa8vMb48M5zuDNtxoQZrVKvh4T4Gn/a10GrdkUTJCH7KrbuwEUZ4UhGjMtxn/yGXiop5uVGVbQGemej/oWMGS6RDeAE).

The basic principle is adopted from Arnauld, but this iterates.
And it takes good advantage from PHP´s implicit typecasts:
NULL to int for string index, float to int for `%`, boolean to int for `&` and for `+=`.

**explanation with pseudo code**

```
If $x is 0, print a newline. ("\n"[$x] is newline for $x=0; empty for every larger $x)
if $y is neither 9 nor 10 (not middle part: $y<9|$y>10 <=> $y%11<9)
AND distance to center == abs(9.5-$x) (in [0.5,1.5,..,10.5]) ->
    lower part:     abs($y-10-distance)>1                   => ($y-distance)%11<9
                (this works because $y is always <20)
    upper part: $x<9|$x>10 <=> distance>1 <=> 10-distance<9 => (10-distance)%11<9
                (this works because % has negative results for negative first operands)
    both parts: $y>9?$y:10 <=> max($y,10)
// $a?:$b evaluates to $a if $a is truthy, to $b else
// and the ternary condition evaluates to 1 if the coords are not in the shape
then print chr(31+1) = space
else print chr(31+incremented $c)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 53 bytes

```
js.e@[+L*9;cb2c2b.e+*-8Ydj*yYdZcL2cb4)kcsrdC127,18 60
```

A program that prints the result.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@59VrJfqEK3to2VpnZxklGyUpJeqraVrEZmSpVUZmRKV7GOUnGSimZ1cXJTibGhkrmNooWBm8P8/AA)

**How it works**

`srdC127` creates a list of the printable ASCII characters and concatenates this to a string.

`c....,18 60` splits this string at indices `18` and `60`, giving a list of three strings corresponding to the different parts of the output: the top, the middle and the bottom.

`.e` begins an enumerated map over the strings with the strings as `b` and their indices as `k`.

`[...)` creates a list containing the desired action for each part of the diagram. The correct action is chosen by indexing into the list with the current index, using `@...k`.

- *Top*

  `cb2` splits the string into pairs of characters, and `+L*9;` prepends `9` spaces to each pair.
- *Middle*

  `c2b` splits the string into two equal-length strings.
- *Bottom*

  `cL2cb4` splits the string into groups of four characters, and each group into pairs.

  `.e` begins an enumerated map, with the string pairs as `Z` and their indices as `Y`.

  `j*yYdZ` joins the pairs on `2*Y` spaces, and `+*-8Yd` prepends `8-Y` spaces.

`js` merges all the results and joins the resulting list on newlines. This is then implicitly printed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 144 bytes

```hs
b!n=[1..n]>>b
('*':r)#(a:s)=a:r#s
(a:r)#s=a:r#s
r#s=r
p="**"
f=unlines([" "!9++p]!9++["*"!21]!2++[" "!(8-n)++p++" "!(2*n)++p|n<-[0..8]])#[' '..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#LYnLCsMgFET3foWPhS8ijatUan6iS3FhoIFAexFNdv13a0IXM8yZ0xYCPozGQJznBQmuuCuSieSq9MkVVlHf/al/6vEFZU@Vomj1B7w3eFURKKbkrnWOZweqKLFjJPbc3YhpANmt1hdZddEXHkO4GTPFKFngmBsT2ydtgD3Ox/7cC17bDw)

**Explanation:**

`b!n=[1..n]>>b` defines a function `!` which repeats a list or string `b` `n`-times.

`unlines([" "!9++p]!9++["*"!21]!2++[" "!(8-n)++p++" "!(2*n)++p|n<-[0..8]])` uses this function to draw an asterisk of asterisks (Oh, the irony!):

```hs
         **
         **
         **
         **
         **
         **
         **
         **
         **
*********************
*********************
        ****
       **  **
      **    **
     **      **
    **        **
   **          **
  **            **
 **              **
**                **
```

`#` is defined as a function which consecutively replaces `*` in a string with chars from a given list. It's called with the above asterisk of asterisks and `[' '..]` which is an infinite list of all characters starting with the space `' '`.

Comment: Super late to the party here, but that `" "!(2*n)` can be `"(TWO SPACES)"!n`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 39 bytes (noncompeting)

```
ＧＨ↑χ→⁴↓χ→¹¹↓⁴←χ↘χ←⁴↖⁹←²↙⁹←⁴↗χ←⁹↑⁴→⁹ ↓¤γ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nuXv96x41DbxfPujtkmPGrc8apsMZh7aeWgnkA0WmQASmQEiJoD50x41AuUmHNr0qG0mhAkWng5VARSYCBYAmrdTAWjIoSXnNv///183EQA) AST provided for explanation, `χ` being the preinitialized variable for `10`.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 63

<s>(not competing)</s>

```
a.{~32>.31+20 21$(* +/\),(9 21&$@{.,1:,1:,}.)(+.1&|."1)|.=|i:10
```

the expression evaluates right to left thus:

- `i: 10` counts from -10 to +10
- `|` take abs to get +10 to 0 back to +10
- `=` self classify to get V shape of 1's in a block of 0's
- `|.` reverse row order to get /\ shape
- `( +. 1&|."1 )` hook expression shifts each row right by one and OR's with original
- `( 9 21&$@{. , 1: , 1: , }. )` nested forks to put in horizontals and stretch top
- `,` to raze the block into a linear sequence for cumulation
- `( * +/\ )` cumulate and multiply with self
- `20 21 $` revert shape to a block 20 rows of 21 elements
- `31 +` add 31 because first 1 should be a space char code 32
- `32 >.` floor at 32
- `a. {~` pick chars from ascii built-in

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! How come you marked this as not competing?

Comment: I just thought I'd add my effort even though it's a long time [15mths] after the competition was launched .. are you saying each puzzle stays open? .. also for J expression to print outside the REPL, i.e when executed in a script I'd need to prefix `smoutput` command or equivalent

Comment: Challenges generally stay open indefinitely (even if an answer has already been accepted). There are some special types of challenges that sometimes get closed to new entries (answer-chaining, cops-and-robbers, king-of-the-hill come to mind), but those will usually say so in the challenge description. As for whether this is a valid answer format, you'd have to ask someone with more J experience, but REPL answers are generally fine as long as they're marked as such.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 209 bytes

```
proc I {} {incr ::i}
proc A {} {time {append a [$::F %c [I]]} 21;puts $a}
set i 31
time {puts [[set F format] %10c%c [I] [I]]} 9
A
A
time {puts [$F %[expr 32-[I]/4]c%c $i [I]][$F %[expr $i/2-45]c%c [I] [I]]} 9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxCoMwFEX3fMUd4ijWaIemk4vgN4QMIU0hUDXEFAqSb081dpDytvPuOUG/UnJ@1hiwRqx20h6c20gy7DIMdjRYlXNmekBBUM57FBpikDKC1Xf3DguoimQxARZNTQ4lcyF22uM5@1EFiaK@6EP@BW6k2@5s0C0vzMd5NKzcRlUrd4XabJze1FasbK/yL5jSFw)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 212 bytes

```
proc I {} {incr ::i}
proc A {} {time {append a [$::F %c [I]]} 21;puts $a}
set i 31
time {puts [[set F format] %10c%c [I] [I]]} 9
A
A
time {puts [$F %[expr (129-[I])/4]c%c $i [I]][$F %[expr $i/2-45]c%c [I] [I]]} 9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYwxCoMwAEX3nOIPEdpBbKwdTCcXwTOEDCFNIVA1xBQK4tlTjR2k/O3x3wv6FaPzo0aHecFsB@3BuV1Igk2CwfYGs3LODA8oCMp5i0xDdFIuKNndvcMEqhYymQCLKyO7krgQG23xHH2vgkTGLnqXf4GaNOuOBl3zwnycx4mVdb7ezkUlN4vaJB0e1BZlXt3kXzPGLw)

## tcl, 213

```
proc I {} {incr ::i}
set F format
proc A {} {time {append a [$::F %c [I]]} 21;puts $a}
set i 31
time {puts [$F %10c%c [I] [I]]} 9
A
A
time {puts [$F %[expr (129-[I])/4]c%c $i [I]][$F %[expr $i/2-45]c%c [I] [I]]} 9
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/LFEB11678)

---

## tcl, 214

```
proc I {} {incr ::i}
set F format
proc A {} {time {append a [$::F %c [I]]} 21;puts $a}
set i 31
time {puts [$F %10c%c [I] [I]]} 9
A
A
time {I;puts [$F %[expr (129-$i)/4]c%c $i [I]][$F %[expr $i/2-45]c%c [I] [I]]} 9
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/JEMW16013)

---

## tcl, 227

```
proc I {} {incr ::i}
set F format
proc A {} {time {append ::a [$::F %c [I]]} 21}
set i 31
time {puts [$F %10c%c [I] [I]]} 9
A
set a $a\n
A
puts $a
time {I;puts [$F %[expr (129-$i)/4]c%c $i [I]][$F %[expr $i/2-45]c%c [I] [I]]} 9
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/JBUH59594)

## tcl, 236

```
proc I {} {incr ::i}
set F format
proc A {} {time {append ::a [$::F %c [I]]} 21}
set i 31
time {puts [$F %10c%c [I] [I]]} 9
set a ""
A
set a $a\n
A
puts $a
time {I;puts [$F %[expr (129-$i)/4]c%c $i [I]][$F %[expr $i/2-45]c%c [I] [I]]} 9
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/GPUF93611)

---

## tcl, 237

```
proc I {} {incr ::i}
set F format
proc A {} {time {set ::a $::a[$::F %c [I]]} 21}
set i 31
time {puts [$F %10c%c [I] [I]]} 9
set a ""
A
set a $a\n
A
puts $a
time {I;puts [$F %[expr (129-$i)/4]c%c $i [I]][$F %[expr $i/2-45]c%c [I] [I]]} 9
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/OMYQ85419)

---

## Alternative approach with same size:

```
proc I {} {incr ::i}
set F format
proc A b {time {upvar $b c;set c $c[$::F %c [I]]} 21}
set i 31
time {puts [$F %10c%c [I] [I]]} 9
set a ""
A a
set a $a\n
A a
puts $a
time {I;puts [$F %[expr (129-$i)/4]c%c $i [I]][$F %[expr $i/2-45]c%c [I] [I]]} 9
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/IOBOX27151)

## Tcl, 288

```
lassign {set while puts format incr expr} S W P F I E
$S i 31
$W \$i<48 {$P [$F %10c%c [$I i] [$I i]]}
$S a ""
$W {[$I i]<71} {$S a $a[$F %c $i]}
$S a $a\n
$W \$i<92 {$S a $a[$F %c $i];$I i}
$P $a
$W \$i<128 {$P [$F %[$E (129-$i)/4]c%c $i [$I i]][$F %[$E $i/2-45]c%c [$I i] [$I i]]; $I i}
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/LCYE76159)

---

## tcl, 297 bytes (naïve attempt)

```
set i 31
while \$i<48 {puts [format %10c%c [incr i] [incr i]]}
set a ""
while {[incr i]<71} {set a $a[format %c $i]}
set a $a\n
while \$i<92 {set a $a[format %c $i];incr i}
puts $a
while \$i<128 {puts [format %[expr (129-$i)/4]c%c $i [incr i]][format %[expr $i/2-45]c%c [incr i] [incr i]]; incr i}
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/OBDN21372)

Comment: What do you mean by "naïve attempt"? Shouldn't you put the length in the title instead?

Comment: I mean there is space for golfing it more, because there is still much repetition. And I will golf it more.

Comment: [Raw approach](http://rextester.com/NXZGP85179) has 254 byte extent.

Comment: [209](https://tio.run/##XYwxCsMgAEV3T/EHM4Y2aTrUTlkCOYM4iLUgNIkYA4Xg2a01HaT87X3e8@oVo3WLwog9YDezcmDMBJJhn6E3k8YurdXzAxKcMjagUuCjEAFtc7ebX0FlIKv2MLg05FAy5/xLBzwXN0kvUDVndci/wI30aaVBU57rt3UpVVNz6kRpFHf62rq7ir9gjB8)

Comment: @ASCII-only: Thanks. Mine is not exactly equal to your suggestion! ;)

Comment: I changed it a bit so the arguments are all `[I]`, but yeah that works too

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 91 bytes

```
->{(-11..8).map{|i|["%s"*21,"%#{9-i}s%s%#{i*2+1}s%s","%10s%s"][i/2<=>-1]}*$/%[*' '..?~,$/]}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
->{(-11..8).map{|i|            #For each line
  ["%s"*21,                    #If i/2==-1 make a format string of 21 %s
   "%#{9-i}s%s%#{i*2+1}s%s",   #If i/2>-1 make a format string %{9-i}s%s%{i*2+1}s%s
   "%10s%s"][i/2<=>-1]         #If i/2<-1 make a format string %10s%s
  }*$/%                        #Join the format strings with newlines $/ then use sprintf operator %
  [*' '..?~,$/]                #to replace the %s with *' '..'~' and a newline for last corner.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I missed an answer in C# so...

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>175</strike> 174 bytes

```cs
_=>{var r="";for(int i=0,j,d=32,s=1;i<54;i++)for(j=0;j++<"*#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#+K)%1###/#%#-#'#+#)#)#+#'#-#%#/###1#"[i]-33;)r+=(char)(i%2<1?32:d++)+(s++%21<1?"\n":"");return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9BasMwELz7FULCVKrsJLbTS2Slh0IvpVDooYc2BCHbqUwiwUoJlOC3u3IKKZTOwO4yM8uy2ufaQTuiCL1X3qMXcDtQh2RSzpc6wQcVjEYnZxr0rIyl7Gr9hia8fvnQHmaPR6trH8DYXYZ@@hp1SCbjVq7PJwUIJMaic0CNDcjIRdZnjazKzMtCmPpuKQznbPJ7uRA95zW@Jcs/5E8sLQghc5KSnNwQTlgkj1MelXl0CoLfzSavKsGAS6o/FTBq0rIu7qty1cQTnHrO07KICv6weIUxE9CGI1gEYhhF8t97D856t29nb2BCSzsal5i4BofLNIzf)

- 1 byte saved thanks to Kevin Cruijssen!

Comment: You can save a byte by putting the `int`s inside the for-loop: `for(int i=0,j,d=32,s=1;i<54;i++)for(j=0`

Comment: [172 bytes](https://tio.run/##bU9BasMwELz7FULCVKrspLbTS2Slh0IvpVDIoYcmFCHbqUwiwUoJlOC3u3IKKZTOwO4yM8uy2ufaQTuiCL1X3qNXcDtQh2RSzpc6wQcVjEYnZxr0ooyl7Gr9hiasv3xoD7Ono9W1D2DsLkM/fYU6JJPxQ67OJwUIJMaic0CNDcjIu6zPGlmVmZeFMPX9QhjO2eT3sqpEz3mNb8niD/kzSwtCyJykJCc3hBMWyeOUR2UenYLgd7MVDLik@lMBoyYt6@KhKpdNPMCp5zwti6jgjcVLjJmANhzBIhDDKJL/nnt01rt9O3sDE1ra0bjExDU4XKZh/AY "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 33 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
¬♣╘╣Ye╗}Ω╩Ñ╬↓ï|§≈b↕£♠╨z▐₧3→ÿ≡Δ:╔♫
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=aa05d4b95965bb7deacaa5ce198b7c15f762129c06d07ade9e331a98f0ff3ac90e&i=)

Uses a similar idea to the 05AB1E answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>119</s> 117 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```c
f(c){for(c=0;c<95;c++)printf("%*c%s",c&1?:c<18?10:c<60?:c&2?c/2-30:24-c/4,c+32,c&c<18|c==38|c>58&!(c-63&3)?"\n":"");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBDoIwFAXXcgt/QtNaGkoLBCnYi7gxL6lhYTXoDjl7rZuZTDJQdyClwCG28Fw5Zu0wnTsHKcVrXeIncCpPKN9UgTV@xNQMvtHZvc7FjEdtlNWjaRXqtoK0Jp//7Yt5tpmXbmBHDtVbZoWna6SRSLg9PW5L5KLYikPgwhV7@gE)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, <s>194</s> 188 bytes

```
k,l,c,s,r=8,0,chr,' ',range;o=''.join(map(chr,r(32,127)))
for i in r(0,18,2):print s*9+o[i:i+2]
print o[18:39]+'\n'+o[39:60]
for i in r(60,95,4):print s*k+o[i:i+2]+s*l+o[i+2:i+4];k-=1;l+=2
```

Comment: You can drop 2 bytes by changing `map(chr` to `map(c` as `c` has already been defined as `chr`

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 180 bytes

```
foreach((range(9)|[9,2]),(range(2)|[0,21]),(range(9)|[8-.,2,.+.,2]))as$r({s:[range(32;127)]|implode};.r=$r|.p=""|until(.r==[];.p+=" "*.r[0]+.s[:.r[1]]|.s =.s[.r[1]:]|.r=.r[2:]);.p)
```

Expanded

```
foreach (                              # instruction sequence: [indent, count]
    (range(9)|[9,2]),                  # 9 rows of 2 characters indented 9 spaces
    (range(2)|[0,21]),                 # 2 rows of 21 characters
    (range(9)|[8-.,2,.+.,2])           # 9 rows of 4 characters with varying indent
) as $r (
    {s:[range(32;127)]|implode}        # state = ascii string
  ; .r = $r                            # current instruction
  | .p = ""                            # print string for this row
  | until(.r==[];                      # until current instruction is exhausted
        .p += " "*.r[0] + .s[:.r[1]]   # add to print string
      | .s = .s[.r[1]:]                # remove from state
      | .r = .r[2:]                    # remove from instruction
    )
  ; .p                                 # emit print string
 )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtBDoIwFAWvQoiLVtofqAsF0pM0XRBFxWBbW4gL69WtHzVx92Yy73JL6Wh93@3PhPjOnHpS06hqJjRlPyFQlExUf7MkOw5MMChgSWkXVp48QqO@wUa0ldhSHYerG@2hf7bg5cpHcDLP42ymYSRopNItuELmWb4Gr0pdQFANrkrrCCGTiB9qEL3EKRpN8UJTelk3DdaExLmZx5EPxs0Tgu/u3M4Twhs)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>176</s> <s>173</s> 172 bytes

```java
v->{for(char i=54,j,d=32,s=1;i-->0;)for(j=0;j++<"#1###/#%#-#'#+#)#)#+#'#-#%#/###1%)K+#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#4#*".charAt(i)-33;)System.out.print((i%2<1?d++:32)+(s++%21<1?"\n":""));}
```

Port of [*@Charlie*'s C# .NET answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128012/52210), so make sure to upvote him.
-4 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XZDBboMwDIbvfQqLCC1ZgDbQXRrYtPO0Xir1su2QBdjCaKhIQJoqnp2Zrafpl@Lktxz7c6NGFTfl16xb5Rw8K2MvKwBjfdXXSlewX54AY2dK0PS4hJFJ9KYVHs4rbzTswUIB8xjfX@qup1gNpthETVQWWRq5QkiT322l4Zwt@abYyIbzPLgl23/iTywUhJA1CUlMbggnDMXxFqOzxowgQaI/Vf/oqWFxlkl2@Ha@OiXd4JNzj71r6jgPU5GLhyDUrzbYYQgiE6boZOmuxDHkNMsF4Dy8twhw5filPOEO6MHjTx8vb6DY3wJsoqkd2vbKPs0/)

Answer (score 0):

## Slashes ([///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////)), 324 bytes

```
          !
         "#
         $%
         &'
         ()
         *+
         ,-
         .\/
         01
23456789:;<=>?@ABCDEF
GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[
        \\]^_
       `a  bc
      de    fg
     hi      jk
    lm        no
   pq          rs
  tu            vw
 xy              z{
|}                ~
```

The first (default) action in Slashes is 'print', so the string is printed. The `/` and `\` must be escaped by proceeding `\`s.

Comment: You should add the byte count and preferably a link to an interpreter. It looks rather ungolfed though (not sure if it's better to do better in ///).

Comment: It's somewhat of a joke to show the beauties of ///, and I will add those!